# Meta refresh tag works locally (on WebLogic server), but not remotely

Tags: web-hosting, redirects, meta-tags, jsp

I have a development environment on my machine and a remote shared development environment. Both have "identically" configured WebLogic 10.3 servers.

On my local dev environment, the meta tag below works as expected. However, upon being deployed to the mirroring WebLogic 10.3 server, the meta tag no longer works:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=sessionTimedOut.jspx"/>
```

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <f:view>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=sessionTimedOut.jspx"/>
    <af:document id="d1" title="#{backing_login.appTitle} - Logged Out">
    <af:resource type="javascript"/>
</af:document>
</f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

The browser I'm using is IE9, and the Weblogic install is essentially a default installation. The changes made were creating a domain and establishing JDBC connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem turned out to be Internet Explorer 9 Zone Security settings. The 'Allow META REFRESH' option was enabled for intranet sites, but disabled for external sites.